# Create a constant date format in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was using CI as my framework. How can I set a CONSTANT date format so that I don't need to change and search for `date("y-m-d")` in all file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this is a common header file:

```php
define('my_date_format', 'y-m-d');
```

To use the constant:

```php
// remember to include the header file first
date(my_date_format);
```

To format `2010-11-10 10:12:11` to `date(m.d.y)`:

```php
$myDate = new DateTime('2010-11-10 10:12:11');
$myDate->format('m.d.y');
```

Comment: Whoa. What are the chances of randomly picking almost identical fake variable names in simultaneous answers? :p

Comment: just a coincidence. interesting.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor this is my date string 2010-11-10 10:12:11 how can it be formated? to date(m.d.y).

Comment: Constants should be written in UPPER CASE.

Comment: @mocca: solution is added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Shivan Raptor

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried exactly what you're asking for, but somewhere you should be able to use the `define` function to define a constant string matching your format, which you can then reference throughout your app.

Example:

```
define( 'MY_DATE_FORMAT', "y-m-d" );

$date = date( MY_DATE_FORMAT );
```

Where you put this in CodeIgniter is a whole other problem. I'll look through the docs and see what I can find.

HTH.

**EDIT:** Found this forum topic on the CI site: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/185794/ It should get you started on what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you say "constant" date format you mean you want the same output each time, but you don't literally need a constant in the PHP sense. Just write your own function (or in Codeigniter terms, "helper"):

```
// Apply your default format to $format
function display_date($timestamp = NULL, $format = 'y-m-d')
{
    // Possibly do some stuff here, like strtotime() conversion
    if (is_string($timestamp)) $timestamp = strtotime($timestamp);

    // Adjust the arguments and do whatever you want!

    // Use the current time as the default
    if ($timestamp === NULL) $timestamp = time();

    return date($format, $timestamp);
}
```

Example usage:

```
echo display_date(); // Current time
echo display_date($user->last_login); // Formatted unix time
echo display_date('Next Monday'); // Accept strings
```

Writing your own function allow much more flexibility in the future.